# Enable WPF button based on checkbox list selection MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0, prism

I have a checkbox list of sports which is bound to an observable collection using the MVVM pattern.
The user can select any number of sports he\she enjoys and when the OK button is pressed the selected sports must be displayed in the message box(simplified the code for the sake of the question).

The OK button must be enabled only if one or more sports have been selected, at the moment this is not working.The enabling\disabling of the button is done using `IsValid` , is there any way to execute this method everytime one of the checkboxes is checked?

I cannot use `<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=checkBox1, Path=IsChecked}" />` because there are multiple properties in the dev code which need to be checked for validity before the button can be used and because I'm using Prism, so this **should be achieved using the `IsValid` method** if at all possible.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication13.MVVM.ComboboxWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation"
        xmlns:local="WpfApplication13.MVVM" Title="MainWindow" Height="170" Width="507">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Sports}" Name="lbModules" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                 Height="72" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Text}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="chkModules" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Height="27" Width="70" Margin="3,80,3,3" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                prism:Click.Command="{Binding Path=NewCommand}"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**View Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands;

namespace WpfApplication13.MVVM
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public DelegateCommand<object> NewCommand { get; protected set; }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private ObservableCollection<ListHelper> modules = new ObservableCollection<ListHelper>();
        public ObservableCollection<ListHelper> Sports
        {
            get { return modules; }
            set { modules = value; OnPropertyChanged("Sports"); }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                NewCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            ListHelper item1 = new ListHelper() { Text = "Footbal", IsChecked = false };
            ListHelper item2 = new ListHelper() { Text = "Boxing", IsChecked = false };
            ListHelper item3 = new ListHelper() { Text = "Basketball", IsChecked = false };

            Sports.Add(item1);
            Sports.Add(item2);
            Sports.Add(item3);

            NewCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(NewTemplate, IsValid);
        }

        private bool IsValid(object parameter)
        {
            //TODO:This method must execute EVERYTIME any of the checkboxes are checked\unchecked.(currently not happening)
            //The return value then determines the enabled state of the button.
            return Sports.Any(e => e.IsChecked);
        }

        private void NewTemplate(object parameter)
        {
            //Display a list of selected sports
            string sports = String.Empty;
            Sports.Where(e => e.IsChecked).ToList().ForEach(c => sports += c.Text + " ");
            MessageBox.Show(sports);
        }
    }

    public class ListHelper
    {
        public String Text { get; set; }

        private bool isChecked = false;
        public Boolean IsChecked 
        {
            get { return isChecked; }
            //The setter is executed everytime the checkbox is checked
            set {isChecked = value;}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought, if the setter in ListHelper is executed on checkbox use, and view model seems to be dependent on the ListHelper anyway, why not implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the ListHelper and then listen to these events in the view model? Then in the listening method in the view model you could do the 'RaiseCanExecuteChanged' and it should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to signal a change in availability of the `NewCommand` (which is determined by `IsValid`) when a checkbox is checked/unchecked. You have to call this:

```
NewCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```

whenever `ListHelper.IsChecked` is updated. You will have to come up with a good way of wiring this together. You have several options but the most straightforward is probably providing `ListHelper` with a reference to `MainViewModel` allowing it to call an appropriate method on the view-model.

Or if you want to avoid the strong coupling created you could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `ListHelper` and let `MainViewModel` listen for changes to `IsChecked`.

Comment: IsValid is a method and not a property.It's used to enable\disable the button.I'm new to WPF could you provide an example because I don't understand your suggestion?

Comment: I've changed my ListHelper class to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged.Posting the change as an answer if anyone is interested.Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for your problem is, that the PRISM DelegateCommand doesn't include  requery support. A proper workaround for this problem is described on this  site 
http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/44750?ProjectName=compositewpf

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the ListHelper class as shown below. The button validation is performed as expected now:

```
 public class ListHelper : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private DelegateCommand<object> _command = null;
        private string _propertyName = String.Empty;

        public ListHelper(DelegateCommand<object> command,string propertyName)
        {
            _command = command;
            propertyName = _propertyName;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public String Text { get; set; }

        private bool isChecked = false;
        public Boolean IsChecked 
        {
            get { return isChecked; }
            //The setter is executed everytime the checkbox is checked
            set 
            {
                isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(_propertyName);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null && _command != null)
            {
                _command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the best solution: call

```
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
```

from the setter of your checkbok IsChecked setter:

```
    public bool IsChecked 
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set 
        {
            isChecked = value;
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        }
    }
```

No need to keep a strong reference to the command. Available from .NET 4.0 at least.